# Avro class is not generated

Tags: java, maven, avro

I have a simple avro schema in the path `src/main/resources/avro/Task.avsc`:

```
{
  "namespace": "com.minompi.java_kafka_example.kafka.avro.model",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Task",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "message",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a controller that should use the model, like this:

```
package com.minompi.java_kafka_example;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.minompi.java_kafka_example.kafka.avro.model.Task;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/messages")
public class MessageController {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, Task> kafkaTemplate;

     @PostMapping
    public void publish(@RequestBody Task task) {
        kafkaTemplate.send("minompi", task);
    }
}
```

In pom.xml I have this configuration:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${avro.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schema</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/avro</sourceDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/avro</outputDirectory>
                            <imports>
                                <import>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/avro/Task.avsc</import>
                            </imports>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/java/</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

But when I compile I got the error java:

```
package com.minompi.java_kafka_example.kafka.avro.model does not exist
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Shouldn't that target folder be `src/generated-sources/java` or something? Or perhaps `generated-sources/main/java`? And did you include the generated-sources folder in your classpath? I'm not sure if Maven does that by default.

Comment: What do you suggest to change @Jorn?